# R: Identify first, second, and third dates of multiple columns and rows

Tags: r

I have a dataset where individuals can have multiple rows of data and seven columns where dates have been listed. I'm trying to find the first, second, and third earliest dates.

```
> head(Addim_try)
# A tibble: 6 x 8
       ID HistoryDate1        HistoryDate2        HistoryDate3 HistoryDate4 Date1  Date2  PDate1             
    <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>       <dttm>       <dttm> <dttm> <dttm>             
1 1317051 NA                  NA                  NA           NA           NA     NA     2022-04-05 00:00:00
2 1317051 2021-06-19 00:00:00 2021-07-10 00:00:00 NA           NA           NA     NA     NA                 
3 1317079 2021-08-10 00:00:00 2021-08-31 00:00:00 NA           NA           NA     NA     NA                 
4 1317079 2022-01-21 00:00:00 NA                  NA           NA           NA     NA     NA                 
5 1324163 2022-04-08 00:00:00 NA                  NA           NA           NA     NA     NA                 
6 1324163 2021-08-07 00:00:00 2021-10-09 00:00:00 NA           NA           NA     NA     NA  
1 1279491 2021-06-14 00:00:00 2021-07-12 00:00:00 NA           NA           NA     NA     NA
```

I'm considering first identifying the first, second, and third dose by row (I would show this but suddenly my code isn't working) and then re-shaping my data to wide format (although I'm getting stuck here, so any suggestions on how to re-shape would be helpful)... Any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

We could reshape to 'long' with `pivot_longer` and get the first 3 dates with `slice_min`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
Addim_try %>%
     mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
     pivot_longer(cols = -c(rn, ID), values_to = "Date", values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
    group_by(rn) %>%
    slice_min(n = 3, order_by = Date) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-rn)
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: Error in `pivot_longer_spec()`:
! Can't combine `ID` <double> and `HistoryDate1` <datetime<UTC>>. Do you know how to combine the two?

Comment: @Almoss277 there was a typo in my post.  It should work now.  I used `-c(rn, -ID)`, it should be `-c(rn, ID)`